# WP7 (windows phone 7) How to save image after zoom with the PhotoCamera?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm using the PhotoCamera for an app and I have done zoom in/out . But I can't figure out how to save this zoom in or zoom out image in camera roll,it always going to save as normal size image without zoom.

Does anyone have a lead on how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

`PhotoChooserTask` already has a crop functionality where you may to zoom in and out. You need to setup `ImageWidth` and `ImageHeight` to enable croping after photo was taken.

Comment: Thanks ku6opr for answer, I want to save photo ,taken  when camera in zoom ,i don't want to crop image after capture .